# Белая полоса сверху в саблайм текст 3

Tags: sublime-text

Сидел программировал в саблайм текст 3 и вдруг верхняя полоса стала белой , а раньше была чёрной,
даже когда я запускаю приложение верхняя полоса тоже белая, как это исправить? Буду очень благодарен

Как было:

[image: как было]

Как стало:

[image: как стало]

Comment: Это скорее всего относится к настройкам оформления окон Windows, а не к Sublime.

Comment: хмм а к каким если быть точнее настройкам ?

Comment: Персонализация - там смотрите настройки цвета.

Comment: всё решил, извините за тупой вопрос (если он был)   )))